# How to create your own financial year and group historical data accordingly

Tags: mysql, database

Can you help me , I have been trying to fetch data for past and current financial year ,

I have data from 2020 till date but i want the data to be grouped on financial year i.e April to March
I have tried filtering data but can only filter it for a specific period like date>=April-21 <= March-22
and grouped by Year_month(date) but this will only show me data for that sepcific date period but how do i pull the whole data in the same format of a financial year

```
Select str_to_date(concat(date_format(DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS Month_Year, 
       Count(Id)
from ABC 
where DATE>="2020-01-01" 
and DATE<=Curdate()
group by str_to_date(concat(date_format(DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS Month_Year
```

What i got is this

```
Jan-20 dec-20  100
Jan-21 dec-21 500
Jan-22 Mar-22 300
```

Output Required is

```
Apr-20 to Mar-21  - 80
Apr-21 to Mar-22  - 700
```

Answer (score 0):

To group by a financial year that runs from the 1st April to 31st March you can use `date_add()` to subtract 3 months from the date before applying the function `year()`.

> ```
>  create table accounts(sales_amount int,trans_date date);
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-1-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-2-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-3-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-4-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-5-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-6-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-7-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-8-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-9-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-10-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-11-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2020-12-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-1-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-2-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-3-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-4-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-5-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-6-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-7-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-8-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-9-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-10-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-11-01');
> insert into accounts values(100,'2021-12-01');
> ```

> ```
> select 
>   sum(sales_amount) turnover,
>   concat('',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval -3 month) ) ,
>     '-',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval +9 month) ) 
>     ) financial_year
> from accounts
> group by  
>   concat('',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval -3 month) ) ,
>     '-',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval +9 month) ) 
>     )  
> order by  
>   concat('',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval -3 month) ) ,
>     '-',
>     year(date_add(trans_date, interval +9 month) ) 
>     )
> ```
>
> ```
> turnover | financial_year
> -------: | :-------------
>      300 | 2019-2020     
>     1200 | 2020-2021     
>      900 | 2021-2022
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8fe8a5f605f385b51ab0420a171d5a76)*

Answer (score 0):

you can used the `between` in `mysql`. Correct me if I'm wrong, but In my persfective in the question you asked, you need to fetch the data from the date of Currect date (Month of March) to next month(April)?

If yes try this.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS Month_Year, COUNT(Id)
FROM ABC WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATE((CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y-%m'), '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS Month_Year
```